# Insert Google Tag Manager after opening body tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I know that I can prepend some html to a page by using [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and the `afterbegin` position like this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
x.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<!-- GTM code goes here -->');
```

**Here's the problem:**

- If I add this code to the `head`, it won't work because the body doesn't exist yet.
- If I add this code to the `body`, it's already too late.

Is there something similar that can go into the head that initializes once the body tag is created?

Comment: Let me ask you this, when will you run your JS?

Answer (score 1):

You could put this into the `<head>` section:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.innerHTML = "[GTM JS goes here]";
    document.body.insertBefore(script, document.body.firstChild);
  });
</script>
```

Make sure you only place the part from within `<script>` from the GTM code into the illustrated placeholder.